# Intersection of iterative ranges of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator acting on a complex Banach space $(X,\|.\|).$ It is  well known that the range  $T(X)$ is always a  Banach space (even if it is not closed) for the norm $\|.\|_{T}$ defined by:  For $y\in T(X),$ $\|y\|_{T}=\mbox{inf}\{\|x\|: Tx=y\}.$   So $(T^{n}(X),\|.\|_{T^{n}})$ is also a  Banach space for all integer $n\geq 0.$

Is there an arbitrary  norm  in which $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} T^{n}(X)$ is a Banach space? I think that the answer is generally no, but I'm having trouble building the examples.

Comment: You should add some requirements. For example if $T(X)=X$ but $T$ is not injective then the original norm on $X$ makes the space a Banach space but  does not coincide with the norm on $T(X).$ Perhaps you may require that the norm on the intersection of the ranges should be the limit of the norms on $T^n(X)$ ?

Comment: No, if $T$ is onto or  $T(X)$ is closed (or more generally $T(X)$ is a Banach space for another norm that $\|\|_{T},$ which is continuously embedded in $X$)  then these norms induced the same topology since  $\|\|_{T}$  is continuously embedded in $X.$

Comment: What I meant was that  Banach space could be complete with respect to many inequivalent norms.